# How do I increase the result presented by my "for loop"?

Tags: c++, for-loop

```
for (int j=1; j<=120; j++){

Pop=10180000;            //Pop = Population //
Increase=Pop*0.0118;
Pop=Increase+Pop;


cout<< Increase <<endl;
cout<< Pop <<endl;

}
```

I am really new here, sorry if I made a mistake. I am suppose to find out the amount of population (10.18mil) for 120 months with the increase of 1.18% every month.

I managed to find the first month but my for loop repeats the same result every line for the next 120 lines.

Comment: Move Pop=10180000 above the for loop, it should be outside otherwise you are resetting your calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're setting the *initial* value of the population every iteration of the loop. You should be doing that *once* before the loop starts.

You can also simplify the calculation since a 1.18% increase can be achieved by just multiplying by `1.0118`. That gives you something like:

```
int Pop = 10180000;
for (int i = 1; i <= 120; i++)
    Pop = Pop * 1.0118;
cout << Pop << endl;
```

---

Of course, if you were writing real code, you may want to factor out the functionality so that it could be re-used easily:

```
int increaseValue(
    int          value,
    double       ratePerPeriod,
    unsigned int periodCount
) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < periodCount; i++)
        value *= (ratePerPeriod / 100.0 + 1.0);
    return value;
}

:

cout << increaseValue(10180000, 1.18, 120) << endl;
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I have another question and that is how did 1.18% turns into 1.0118? My math isn't that good, sorry if the question seems stupid.

Comment: @mrtammy: a 5% increase (for example) is adding the original value (`x`) and another 5% (`x * 0.05`). This gives `(x * 1) + (x * 0.05)`, which becomes `x * (1 + 0.05)`, then `x * 1.05`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you re-initialize `Pop` as 10180000 at the start of each iteration. You should move it above the loop so that its value does not get reset at each iteration.

```
Pop=10180000;            //Pop = Population //
for (int j = 1; j <= 120; j++) {
  Increase=Pop*0.0118;
  Pop=Increase+Pop;

  cout<< Increase <<endl;
  cout<< Pop <<endl;
}
```